# Combine and concatenate rows with certain values

Tags: sql, concatenation

I am trying to combine values in a database so that it is easier for those that aren't software developers but can't think of a solution for this. An example of what the database would look like is below. When a technician changes an existing value for a company like it's city name it creates 3 entries like this below.

What I am trying to do is concatenate it into something like `"{user} updated {old city} to {new city}"`. I want to put that in a new column called Description for the row with the "new value" flag but don't want to touch rows that don't have "old value" or "new value" since there are many different flags being used for the types of changes they might be making. I am not really sure how to go about combining rows like this.

The section labeled `"num"` is specific to each change being made and only a group like the one in the example will have the same value there so I was thinking maybe I could somehow use group by to weed out any changes that were made that only required one row since I am only looking for chunks with the format like the one below.

```
_ id_|_CompName   |_val_flag | value _|num|user|______updated______  
1224 |Test company|old_value |Old City|594|user|2017-07-28 15:42:58.117  
1225 |Test company|new_value |New City|594|user|2017-07-28 15:42:58.117  
1226 |Test company|rec_value |New City|594|user|2017-07-28 15:42:58.117
```

Comment: What is the database? Version #? Also, what is the significance of "REC_VALUE" record? Should we consider it? Look like "GROUP BY" USER is where one to start with. Is "CITY" column name? So, NEW CITY and OLD CITY is internally related? If so, need to write the GROUP BY based on USER and VALUE (second half, minus NEW/OLD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of questions to begin with.

- What is the database? Version #?
- Also, what is the significance of "REC_VALUE" record? Should we consider it?

Looks like "GROUP BY" USER is where to start with. Write the GROUP BY based on USER and NUM.

Something like below. Oracle SQL syntax (untested).

```
SELECT USER ||' updated ' || OLD_VAL || ' to ' || NEW_VAL AS DESCRIPTION
FROM (
SELECT AUD.USER
, MAX(CASE WHEN _VAL_FLAG = 'old_value' THEN VALUE END) OLD_VAL
, MAX(CASE WHEN _VAL_FLAG = 'new_value' THEN VALUE END) NEW_VAL
FROM AUDIT_TABLE AUD
GROUP BY AUD.USER, NUM)
```

Comment: Thanks I just saw you answered now because I didn't get an email notification but this works! I was running through ideas during the weekend and I was thinking of using cases. Also the rec value isn't really important it's just a 3rd value that the database uses every time a change is made to save what was change. This query is for a database that stores all of our companies client info.